# Trigger specific constructor for a member in the member initialisation list based on a flag

Tags: c++

I would like to trigger a specific constructor for a member variable based on flags I pass to the containing class's constructor.

It's easiest if I start with a trivial example:

```
#include <boost/optional.hpp>
#include <boost/none.hpp>
#include <boost/utility/typed_in_place_factory.hpp>

struct state
{
  bool flag1;
  bool flag2;
  int value;
};

class A
{
public:
  A() : _a() {}
  A(boost::none_t none) : _a() {}
  A(state& st) : _a(st.value) {}
  A(const A& copy) : _a(copy._a) {}

private:
  boost::optional<int> _a;
};

class B
{
public:
  B() : _b() {}
  B(boost::none_t none) : _b() {}
  B(state& st) : _b(st.value) {}
  B(const B& copy) : _b(copy._b) {}

private:
  boost::optional<int> _b;
};

class C
{
public:
  C() : _a(boost::none_t()), _b(boost::none_t()) {}
  C(state& st) :
    _a(st.flag1 ? st : boost::none_t()),
    _b(st.flag2 ? st : boost::none_t())
  {}

private:
  boost::optional<A> _a;
  boost::optional<B> _b;
};

int main(void)
{
  state f = { true, false, 10 };
  C c(f);

  return 0;
}
```

So the idea is to trigger the constructor for `A` with `state`, but `B` with `boost::none_t`.
The above code does not compile because the ternary operator is expecting the same type for both possibilities, and `state` and `boost::none_t` are not the same type.
Can anyone think of an elegant way around this?

I know of two solutions:

1. Copy construct, i.e.

   `_a(st.flag1 ? A(st) : A(boost::none_t())),
   _b(st.flag2 ? B(st) : B(boost::none_t()))`
2. Use pointers instead of `boost::optional<>`, then

   `_a(st.flag1 ? new A(st) : new A(boost::none_t())),
   _b(st.flag2 ? new B(st) : new B(boost::none_t()))`

#2 is not so appealing, as I'm trying to avoid dynamic memory allocation (the real example has tens of members and deeply nested structures with more members).
#1 is also not appealing as I would need to construct and then copy.

Is there a better alternative?

**EDIT**:  `state` is modified by the members on construction, so I don't want to construct something with `state` if the flag is not set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that using `boost::optional<>` is complicating things, using it with the copy constructed approach seems to cause both the `state` based and copy based constructors of `A` & `B` to be called - even with full optimization.

However, if I define the members of `C` as simply `A _a` and `B _b`, the copy constructor is actually optimised away, so doing

```
_a(st.flag1? A(st) : A()), _b(st.flag2? B(st) : B())
```

Is actually apparently the most optimal way of getting this to work, I just have to workaround the other functionality I was using from boost::optional<> (i.e. initialized vs. uninitialized).

Answer (score 3):

You have to learn to trust your compiler's optimiser to inline this kind of thing adequately, or you'll restrict yourself from using 99% of the Standard libraries and advanced C++ facilities.

Start by looking at the boost optional API:

```
...
optional(bool condition, T const&);
...
```

Which suggests adding a matching constructor...

```
A(bool condition, T const& v) : _a(condition, v) { }
```

...and using it in your initialisation...

```
_a(st.flag1, st.value)
```

Comment: I do trust the optimizer to do a better job than I, but only when I understand what it's doing. I will mark your answer up for the suggestion, however it still does a copy construct, and infact is more damaging that the first option I have above (reason being that `state` is modified as members are constructed and with this approach, `A` & `B` are constructed with `state` irrespective of whether the flag is set or not.)

Comment: @Nim: the boost docs say of that constructor: if condition is true it's equivalent to optional(v), otherwise optional(), which suggests the boolean is consulted and either the optional's bool or state set - no unnecessary copying/init of state.  It copy constructs the optional but not A or B - this is more targetted and appropriate, and I fully expect the optimiser to remove this.

Comment: good call for this version of `optional` constructor! This (alone) solves the problem of the OP. The OP is not trying to build a `A` but an `optional<A>`, thus it is unnecessary to add a `A` constructor for this. However it means that `A(st)` will always be executed (before being passed to `optional`) and since this is guaranteed by the standard (because of the potential side-effects) this might affect the semantics of the constructor. The behavior is thus different from the ternary operator, especially since `Nim` precised that `st` is modified by `A` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I would expect the copy constructor approach to work, because as stated it solves the issue of types for the ternary operator. However I do not know if the copy could be optimized away.

From a readability point of view though, I would prefer:

```
boost::optional<A> buildA(state& st) { return st.flag1 ? A(st) : A(); }
boost::optional<B> buildB(state& st) { return st.flag2 ? B(st) : B(); }

C::C(state& st): _a(buildA(st)), _b(buildB(st)) {}
```

which is slightly more verbose. The optimization of the copy remains a good question.

*Note:* why do you use a `state&` ? From this short example a `state const&` would be better since no reference is taken from `st`.

Comment: I was thinking along the lines that the copy may be optimized away as well, but wasn't so sure - is there any way to confirm? As for the reason why I'm taking a reference, in the real code, the contents of state will be modified as each member is initialised, (I left it the same here, but you are right, for this example I could have made it const!)

Comment: @Nim: the usual way is to look at the assembly produced, which is quite tedious, but the only portable way (without execution) to look at the product of a compiler. If you use Clang, you could get a dump of the AST produced, if I remember correctly copy elision is mentioned in the AST... but no guarantee there. If you can execute the compiled code, then a trace in the copy constructor :)

Comment: @Metthieu, hmm going to have to leave that for a learning exercise for later, with traces and even with O3 (gcc 4.4.4), I can see that both the state and copy constructors are triggered... :(